# In a Laravel application I am returning phpinfo() when I run the project folder

Tags: laravel

I installed backup of website from live server to localhost in xampp. But when I run the project I mean that when I type localhost/folder its shows php info file. I don't know why this happening. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Open cmd. Move to your project folder and type there `php artisan serve`

Comment: I already did that

Comment: then type `http://localhost:8000` in the browser

Comment: Dear brother I already did these things but still it shows php info file

Comment: You don't need the `artisan serve` command when using xampp.

Comment: @Jerodev Then you need to type full path to public folder

Comment: erm, no, you just need to put your project in the correct on from your apache webserver.

Comment: For example if your laravel folder is `project` then you need to type `http://localhost/project/public/` which is quite odd I mean.

Comment: I did like that @zain but still in vain

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to configure virtual host on xampp in

> C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost myproject.test:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\public"
  <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also add this to hosts file in

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

```
127.0.0.1  myproject.test
```

Change **myproject** with the name you want.

Comment: file extension to add?

Comment: You already have these files present. Just update them based on the code above. You can skip the second step if you want. This just allows you to map ```myproject.test``` to localhost.

Comment: still facing the same issue

Comment: restart apache so it can load the new settings.

Comment: @Rayin In your public folder `index.php` file exists?

Comment: again same issue no changes :(

Comment: Yes, index file is there in public folder